# How to access the tables for has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have following association.

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  has_one :account_history, through: :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_one :account_history
end

class AccountHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

1. How can I access account table through supplier model
2. How can I access supplier table through account model
3. How can I access join table accounthistory without through other model
4. How can I add a field by migration to accounthistory and then get value from that field through supplier or account model

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is too simplistic, but this what I'd propose:

**1. `@supplier.account`**

```
@supplier = Supplier.find(id)
@supplier.account #-> brings account data
```

---

**2. `@account.supplier`**

```
@account = Account.find(id)
@account.supplier #-> brings supplier data
```

---

**3. `@supplier.account_history`**

```
@supplier = Supplier.find(id)
@supplier.account_history #-> brings account_history
```

---

**4. Migration**

```
def change
    add_column :account_histories, :your_column, :type, after: :column
end
```

You can deal with the join model / table directly (unlike HABTM's), meaning you will be able to create migrations as you wish. The above migration code shows how you can add a column to the table directly

**Delegate**

To access the data from that model, you're in luck

Because you're using a singular association (`has_one` / `belongs_to`), you should be able to [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) the call to another model:

```
#app/models/supplier.rb
Class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  has_one :account_history, through: :account
end

#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier
  has_one :account_history

  delegate :extra, :vars, :here, to: :account_history
end
```

This will allow you to call: `@supplier.account.extra` etc

Hope this helps? Your question was rather scant on context, so I can fix my answer if you update!